# PROBLEMA CON formControlName Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

**Tengo el siguiente problema modifique la logica de como se estaba seteando unos campos en en la modal pero sin embargo eso hizo que la modal se me reviente y me sale el siguiente error** [image: ERROR QUE ME SALE]

*y estos son los metodos que se cargar de setear y el otro que conlleva al de añadir el control al formulario*

Uno se encarga se setear el MaserBatch y el otro dentro del formulario, sin embargo no se si ese error sea porque no estara haciendo el push de todos o que sera

```
setMasterBatch() {
const masterBatc = this.masterBatch.split('|');
for (let i = 1; i < masterBatc.length; i++) {
  if (masterBatc[i] && masterBatc[i].trim() !== 'N/A') {
    this.setFormMasterBatch(i, masterBatc[i], '', '');
  }
}
```

}

```
setFormMasterBatch(index, codMaster, desc, lote) {
this.masterBatchList.push({ tipo: this.getType(index), codMaster: codMaster, desc: desc, lote: lote });
this.formMasterBatch.addControl(index + '-tipo', new FormControl(this.getType(index), []));
this.formMasterBatch.addControl(index + '-codMaster', new FormControl(codMaster, []));
this.formMasterBatch.addControl(index + '-desc', new FormControl(desc, []));
// tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
this.formMasterBatch.addControl(index + '-lote', new FormControl(lote, [Validators.required]));
```

}

y este es el HTML de la modal

```
<form [formGroup]="formAditivos" *ngIf="formAditivos">
                <h5>ADITIVOS TÓPICOS Y SURFACTANTES</h5>
                <hr>
                <table class="table table-bordered table-sm centered-table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr class="thead-dark">
                            <th>Código</th>
                            <th>Descripción</th>
                            <th>Lote</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr *ngIf="!aditivosList.length">
                            <td colspan="3" class="customer-bg-empty">No existen registros para cargar</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr *ngFor="let aditivo of aditivosList; let i = index">
                            <td>{{ aditivo.codAditivo ? aditivo.codAditivo : 'N/A' }}</td>
                            <td>{{ aditivo.desc ? aditivo.desc : 'N/A' }}</td>
                            <td>
                                <input autocomplete="rutjfkde" type="text" id="lostA-{{i + 1}}" name="lostA-{{i + 1}}" formControlName="{{ i + 1 }}-lote" class="form-control form-control-sm" [(ngModel)]="aditivo.lote" [ngClass]="{'border border-danger': validateInputs(i + 1 + '-lote', formAditivos)}">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="mt-5 mb-5">
            <form [formGroup]="formMasterBatch" *ngIf="formMasterBatch">
                <h5>MASTERBATCH, RECUPERADOS Y ADITIVOS EN MASA</h5>
                <hr>
                <table class="table table-bordered table-sm centered-table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr class="thead-dark">
                            <th>Tipo</th>
                            <th>Código</th>
                            <th>Descripción</th>
                            <th>Lote</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr *ngIf="!masterBatchList.length">
                            <td colspan="4" class="customer-bg-empty">No existen registros para cargar</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr *ngFor="let master of masterBatchList; let i = index">
                            <td>{{ master.tipo ? master.tipo : 'N/A' }}</td>
                            <td>{{ master.codMaster ? master.codMaster : 'N/A' }}</td>
                            <td>{{ master.desc ? master.desc : 'N/A' }}</td>
                            <td>
                                <input autocomplete="rutjfkde" type="text" id="lostM-{{i + 1}}" name="lostM-{{i + 1}}" formControlName="{{ i + 1 }}-lote" class="form-control form-control-sm" [(ngModel)]="master.lote" [ngClass]="{'border border-danger': validateInputs(i + 1 + '-lote', formMasterBatch)}">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </form>
```

ayuda!!

Comment: La respuesta es sencilla como tiene saltos de index debido a la conicion por ende en necesario hacer addControl a cada una de ellas por es neceesario poner el addControl fuera de la condicion.